# R bfastmonitor, how to extract the calendar date of the breakpoint?

Tags: r, time-series, raster

I am using bfastmonitor on a raster brick to detect a breakpoint in a time series.

I am using bfmSpOver for an area like this:

bfm_area <- bfmSpOver(s, area_shape, fun=mean, start=c(2006, 1), formula = response~harmon+trend, order = 1, h=0.25, history = c("ROC"), level = 0.05)

And my output is:

> bfm_area$breakpoint

[1] 2006.603

Now what date does 2006.603 correspond to? So far I thought the bfm output is shown in year, Julian day, however this does not match this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be August 8 2006? The 365 * 0.603 ~ 220th day of 2006.

The `lubridate` package has a function `date_decimal` you can use to convert your decimal date in to a date object.

Comment: Yes, thank you the lubridate function works perfectly, and I believe your calculation is a very close estimate! (9th of August)

Comment: No problem. I didn't have access to R when I posted that so I had to make a guess :)